# Calling 32 binary from 64 bit application

Tags: com, visual-c++, windows-7-x64

I am working on an application which is in 32 bit. This app is  working fine in 32 bit machine .
 But when I install it in 64 bit machine it does not work properly. So we planned to compile it in 64 bit configuration. We could compile it and tried to run, It works properly.
 But problem is; we have a 3ed party library which is in 32 bit. If I try to call that library from 64 bit, will it create problem, will it work?
I am running it in windows 7 64 bit amchine.
Please guide me to supporting my application to 64 bit.

Comment: AFAIK, You need to have 64bit equivalent for that library. Check the 3rd party site if they have any.

Comment: Umesha, have a look at this: http://www.dnjonline.com/article.aspx?id=jun07_access3264

Comment: @Scott: Wow! Nice one. THanks! Never heard of it till now.

Comment: That 3ed party library is Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. We don’t have 64 bit support library for that.

Comment: @Umesha MS - Can you elaborate on the "does not work properly" part? It sounds to me like it might be worth the effort to fix the issues in the 32 bit build instead.

Comment: I have a com library which creates a namespace extension.  When I try to register it will not get registered. If I convert it to 64 bit, it will get registered and I can see a namespace extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JET database engine will never be ported to 64-bit.  You will have to consider a different engine.  SQL Server Compact or Express are excellent choices.